# iTunes full screen movie won't play

Tags: itunes, fullscreen

I'm using iTunes 10.6.3 64-bit on a 13-inch Mid 2010 MBP running Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.1

When I pause a movie in full-screen mode in iTunes, the resume/play button remains greyed out.  The only fix is to exit full screen mode then resume from a regular window, and then switch back to fullscreen.

How can I resume playback when watching fullscreen content?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using iTunes to play movies? 
go to Macintosh HD\Users\USERNAME\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Movies
there you have the movies you bought (which is why you are using iTunes?)

you should download VLC player, it plays the movies so much better, and it is pretty much bug free.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug (especially when using external screens)

Are you able to upgrade to latest iTunes and OSX to check if it has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue regarding my itune player not been in full screen the SOLUTION I found is this to put my display setting (they were in +/- 4k) back in to regular HD 1080x1920  eureka FULL SCREEN IS BACK

hope this help

ps  I dont understand why itune has never corrected this or inform user (solution) I don't want to buy 4k apple video guizmo to view my purchase content on my PC

All the best, Dave